# Is there any way to disable first option with ion-select interface="action-sheet"?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I want to disable the first option with index 0. Here is my code:

```html
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Select</ion-label>
   <ion-select interface="action-sheet">   
      <ion-option *ngFor="let option of options,let i=index" [disabled]="i==0">
         <span>{{option.title }}</span>
         <span>{{option.description }}</span>
      </ion-option>
   </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: could you please show your options array?

Comment: interface="action-sheet" is this required/optional?

Comment: Here is options Array:-  
  options = [ {
      title: 'Banana',
      description: 'Long curved yellow fruit.'
    },
    {
      title: 'Dog',
      description: 'Man\'s best friend.'
    },
    {
      title: 'Ionic',
      description: 'Modificates the options text.'
    }
  ];

Comment: interface="action-sheet"  is optional .I can use interface="popover".I want to display my list as same as when i am using "interface=action-sheet".

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/533

Here's stated that this issue is related to interface="action-sheet", problem exists for a while now. [disabled]="i==0" should work.